# How to use grep and logical operators inside if statement

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have this code snippet from one of my scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash

abc=4

if "$abc" == "4" && grep https://download.abc.com abc.log; then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

Expected output:

```
True
```

Actual output:

```
./abc.sh: line 5: 4: command not found
False
```

What is wrong in my if statement that throws this syntax error?

Comment: What ar you trying to do here: `grep https://download.abc.com abc.log`.  This part fails

Comment: @Jotne No, the error is that `if "$abc"` tries to run the value of `abc` as a command.

Comment: @Bogdan: The syntax is `if COMMAND; then ....`, and the `if` succeeds if the command returns exit status 0. In your case, the command is `$abc`, which evaluates to `4`, and you don't have a command of this name.

Comment: The fix is `if [[ "$abc" = "4" ]] && grep -q 'https://download.abc.com' abc.log; then`

Comment: this is what I was looking for. I knew it must be some sort of syntax error. thank you.